# Cannot find aspnet_regiis

Tags: iis, windows-7

Where can I find aspnet_regiis on Windows 7 Pro?
I have .NET 4 installed and as far as I understand it is supposed to reside in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`.

I have just installed IIS (after .NET 4).

Do I have to install anything else to get this?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling .NET 4 did the trick...